# How can I access IPv6 statistics on Mac OSX?

Tags: c, macos, ipv6

I would like to get some IPv6 statistics from Mac OSX using `sysctl` with `struct ip6stat` which is defined in `netinet6/ip6_var.h` but that header does not appear to be on my system. Why isn't is included and how should I get it there?

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.2, Darwin Kernel 11.2.0, with xnu-1699.24.8. The kernel is clearly compiled with IPv6 enabled, and the [online source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1699.24.8/bsd/netinet6/ip6_var.h) shows it exists. However, the file is not under `/usr/include/netinet6/` where I expected it to be. There are clearly other files missing as well. Anyone know why?

Comment: Here's why: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Macnetworkprog/2005/Sep/msg00078.html

Comment: Ok, well at least that explains why. It's frustrating that their solution is to hide the data structure even though it's clearly in the source they make publicly available! I suppose my last resort is Running netstat as an external command and parsing the output, though that seems equally brittle.

Comment: Right.  They specifically warn against that in the link from the apple mailing list above.  You'll wind up hacking it constantly with updates if only on one system.  Worse, if you need to support mutliple systems, you'll have to support different versions of the structure and check OS version before deciding which to use.

Comment: I guess this is over a year old, but surely there's something that's higher level than the kernel but lower level than netstat, for example calls to glibc. Netstat compiles for different kernels, so if you find out how netstat works and code your program using the same interface...